# Sorting an array of objects by 2 keys with weights for one key

Tags: javascript, sorting

Consider the following array of objects :

```js
var arr = [
  { brand : 'BMW' , year : '2014' },
  { brand : 'Audi' , year : '2018' },
  { brand : 'Benz' , year : '2020' },
  { brand : 'BMW' , year : '2011' },
  { brand : 'Audi' , year : '2015' },
  { brand : 'BMW' , year : '2010' },
  { brand : 'BMW' , year : '2018' }
]
```

so i'm trying to sort this array firstly by brand (Not alphabetically but by a certain weight... so BMW has the highest weight => Audi => Benz ) and secondly by the year ..so i get something like this :

```js
var arr = [
    { brand : 'BMW' , year : '2014' },
    { brand : 'BMW' , year : '2011' },
    { brand : 'BMW' , year : '2010' },
    { brand : 'Audi' , year : '2018' },
    { brand : 'Audi' , year : '2018' },
    { brand : 'Audi' , year : '2015' },
    { brand : 'Benz' , year : '2020' }
 ]
```

this is what i have tried so far but looks like i don't really get how `sort()` functions :

```js
function sortByBrand (a,b) {
    if(a.brand == 'BMW' && b.brand !=='BMW') {
        return 2
    }else if (a.brand == 'Audi' &&  b.brand !=='Audi') {
        return 1
    } else if (a.brand == 'Benz' &&  b.brand !=='Benz') {
        return 0
    }
}

function sortByYear (a,b) {
    return parseInt(b.year) - parseInt(a.year)
}

arr.sort(sortByBrand)
arr.sort(sortByYear)
```

i know this will mutate the first sort but i really don't get how to merge the two sorts together

Comment: It looks like the `{ brand : 'BMW' , year : '2018' }` object gets dropped, is that intentional?  Or should it be at the top of the expected output array?

Comment: You edited your question, but you still didn't make clear what's the criterion for sorting the brands.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado the criteria is string name so consider the following order : BMW => order 1 / Audi => order 2 / Benz => order 3

Comment: Where is *that* order specified in your question? It's just the order of the brand values in the array? If yes, make **that** information clear. In the question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `localeCompare` to check whether one string comes before or after another, which returns 1, 0, or -1. Compare the `.brand` property of each object with `localeCompare`, and if that comes out to 0, compare by the difference in year:

```js
var arr = [
  { brand : 'A' , year : '2014' },
  { brand : 'B' , year : '2018' },
  { brand : 'C' , year : '2020' },
  { brand : 'A' , year : '2011' },
  { brand : 'B' , year : '2015' },
  { brand : 'A' , year : '2010' },
  { brand : 'B' , year : '2018' }
]

arr.sort((a, b) => (
  a.brand.localeCompare(b.brand)
  || b.year - a.year
));

console.log(arr);
```

Keep in mind that the `.sort` callback only cares if the return value is negative, 0, or positive. Returning 2 is the same as returning 1 (and, for the sorting algorithm to be consistent, if `a` compared to `b` returns a positive value, `b` compared to `a` should return a negative value).

If `localeCompare` isn't sophisticated enough, make a function that takes an object and returns the appropriate weight of the brand:

```js
var arr = [
  { brand : 'BMW' , year : '2014' },
  { brand : 'Audi' , year : '2018' },
  { brand : 'Benz' , year : '2020' },
  { brand : 'BMW' , year : '2011' },
  { brand : 'Audi' , year : '2015' },
  { brand : 'BMW' , year : '2010' },
  { brand : 'BMW' , year : '2018' }
];

const weights = {
  BMW: 2,
  Audi: 1,
  Benz: 0
};
const getWeight = ({ brand }) => weights[brand];

arr.sort((a, b) => (
  getWeight(b) - getWeight(a)
  || b.year - a.year
));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Hi thanks sounds great.. but i think the localCompare sorts the strings alphabetically and im trying to sort brands dependently of some criteria .. for example `if(a.brand =='A' ` then i want the brand to be  at the top of my array

Comment: Create an object or map that holds all of the brands mapped to their respective weights and index into it to compare two inside the comparator. `weights = {foo: 2, bar: 1}`, `(a, b) => weights[a] - weights[b] || b.year - a.year`

Comment: @user121548789 Can you explain what exactly the criteria you want are?